# Map's containsKey() fails on serialized objects

Tags: flutter, dart, serialization

I have the following map:

```
Map<MenuItem, int> items = LinkedHashMap();
```

where the contents are being serialized into disk to survive app/device restart. The `items.containsKey()` correctly identifies the same `MenuItem` keys. However, this does not work when the app is restarted. How do I fix this?

EDIT: I believe this issue is also applicable to other serialized objects such as from network data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `LinkedHashMap` [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html), it mentions about the following:

> The keys of a LinkedHashMap must have consistent Object.== and
> Object.hashCode implementations. This means that the == operator must
> define a stable equivalence relation on the keys (reflexive,
> symmetric, transitive, and consistent over time), and that hashCode
> must be the same for objects that are considered equal by ==.

To fix the issue, I had to modify my `MenuItem` class like so:

```
class MenuItem {
  String name;
  String description;
  String price;
  ...

    @override
  String toString() {
    return '{'
        '"name": "$name",'
        '"description": "$description", '
        '"price": "$price"'
        '}';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(other) {
    return other is MenuItem &&
        name == other.name &&
        description == other.description &&
        price == other.price;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {

    // this would work too
    // return hashValues(name, description, price);

    return toString().hashCode;
  }
}
```

Comment: flutter uses [hashValues()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/hashValues.html) function almost everywhere to compute `hashCode` - i believe it is a way to follow

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this and implement in my project. I will update this answer accordingly.